# Search HTML Tables generated with javascript object

Tags: javascript, html, search, html-table

I have an Object with two properties key and value

```
let object = [
     {"key":"apple","value":1.90},

     {"key":"berry","value":1.7},
     {"key":"banana","value":1.5},
     {"key":"cherry","value":1.2} ]
```

now I generated a simple html table using this small snippet

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) { 
var tr = "<tr>";
 if(obj[i].value.toString().substring(obj[i].value.toString().indexOf('.'),obj[i].value.toString().length) < 2)

obj[i].value += "0"; 
 
tr += "<td>" + obj[i].key + "</td>" + "<td>" + 

obj[i].value.toString() + "</td></tr>";

tbody.innerHTML += tr; 

}
```

and wanted to search it similar to how you search an html table, I am successful in searching them but have no idea how to display results, on html I can use the display tag to turn off dynamically and it removes irrelevant results as I press keys, see [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp)

Comment: I'm not entirely 100% but rather than searching any "dynamically generated HTML content" just search the source object and rebuild the html display as necessary

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I was so concerned about searching the already existing tables that I forgot how I got them in the first place, Thank You

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stuck with the same scenario, I suggest you use jauery to generate dynamic tables and then use the same search method to filter the results